# SQL Server CLR function that is attempting to access a WCF service and I keep getting a "System.Security.HostProtectionException" error returned

Tags: sql-server, wcf, clr

I have a simple WCF service that takes a string and return a token.  I then created a CLR function that I can use in SQL Server to apply this when reading some information from the database.  When I try to execute the query "select dbo.fn_token('4111111111111111')" it keeps throwing an error back.

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "fn_Token":
> System.Security.HostProtectionException: Attempted to perform an operation that was forbidden by the CLR host.
> The protected resources (only available with full trust) were: All
> The demanded resources were: SharedState
> System.Security.HostProtectionException:

I have done some research on the web and it appears that this may be happening in the dispose routine, but I could not find an answer on how to correct the issue.

SQL Server:     2019,
Window Version: 2019 Enterprise,
VS Version:     2019,
Framework:      4.6.2 x64

CLR Routine:

```
using Pyxis3.Tokenization.Pyxis3.Tokenization;
using System;

namespace Pyxis3.Tokenization
{
    public class TokenCC
    {
        public static string DeToken(string _token)
        {
            //using (LocalCipherServer _cipher = new LocalCipherServer())
            {
                LocalCipherServer _cipher = new LocalCipherServer();
                return _cipher.GetAccount(_token, "");
            }
        }

        public static string Token(string _account)
        {
            //using (LocalCipherServer _cipher = new LocalCipherServer())
            {
                LocalCipherServer _cipher = new LocalCipherServer();
                return _cipher.GetTokenWithAdd(_account, "");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can the SQL Server CLR function run normally if it is not called through WCF?

Answer (score 0):

You must specified that your assembly has an UNSAFE access in CLR and make your database TRUSTED :

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY assembly_name 
FROM { <client_assembly_specifier> | <assembly_bits> [ ,...n ] }  
[ WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
..
```

and :

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDataBase SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;
```